# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list (Starting ending points as lists)

Tags: python, or-tools

My inputs are like this, i tried to make starting and ending points to control the routing from a point a --> (special scenario of my case: routing is from location 'a' to point 'a')

I try to get a routing with capacity , distance and time windows constraints, at this level, if i execute the code, I visualise the error bellow:

''TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list ''

```
data['time_matrix'] = [
    [0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7],
    [6, 0, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 8, 8, 13, 7, 5, 8, 12, 10, 14],
    [9, 8, 0, 11, 10, 6, 3, 9, 5, 8, 4, 15, 14, 13, 9, 18, 9],
    [8, 3, 11, 0, 1, 7, 10, 6, 10, 10, 14, 6, 7, 9, 14, 6, 16],
    [7, 2, 10, 1, 0, 6, 9, 4, 8, 9, 13, 4, 6, 8, 12, 8, 14],
    [3, 6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 12, 8],
    [6, 8, 3, 10, 9, 2, 0, 6, 2, 5, 4, 12, 10, 10, 6, 15, 5],
    [2, 4, 9, 6, 4, 3, 6, 0, 4, 4, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 8, 10],
    [3, 8, 5, 10, 8, 2, 2, 4, 0, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 3, 13, 6],
    [2, 8, 8, 10, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 5],
    [6, 13, 4, 14, 13, 7, 4, 8, 4, 4, 0, 10, 9, 8, 4, 13, 4],
    [6, 7, 15, 6, 4, 9, 12, 5, 9, 6, 10, 0, 1, 3, 7, 3, 10],
    [4, 5, 14, 7, 6, 7, 10, 4, 8, 5, 9, 1, 0, 2, 6, 4, 8],
    [4, 8, 13, 9, 8, 7, 10, 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6],
    [5, 12, 9, 14, 12, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 4, 7, 6, 4, 0, 9, 2],
    [9, 10, 18, 6, 8, 12, 15, 8, 13, 9, 13, 3, 4, 5, 9, 0, 9],
    [7, 14, 9, 16, 14, 8, 5, 10, 6, 5, 4, 10, 8, 6, 2, 9, 0],
]
    
data['time_windows'] = [
    (0, 5),  # depot
    (7, 12),  # 1
    (10, 15),  # 2
    (16, 18),  # 3
    (10, 13),  # 4
    (0, 5),  # 5
    (5, 10),  # 6
    (0, 4),  # 7
    (5, 10),  # 8
    (0, 3),  # 9
    (10, 16),  # 10
    (10, 15),  # 11
    (0, 5),  # 12
    (5, 10),  # 13
    (7, 8),  # 14
    (10, 15),  # 15
    (11, 15),  # 16
]

data['num_vehicles'] = 4
data['demands'] = [0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 8, 8, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8]
data['vehicle_capacities'] = [15, 15, 15, 15]
data['depot'] = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]
data['ends']= [ 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

My code is :

```
    depot_idx = data['depot']
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
            data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1]) 
        
    # Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
    for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data['time_windows']):
        if location_idx == data['depot']:
            continue
        index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
        time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
```

And when i execute the code it gives me this :

```
<ipython-input-10-8bb55ac15980> in main()
     47         index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
     48         time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
---> 49             data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
     50             data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1]) 
     51 

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

**Can anyone please tell me where and what it is the problem, because I tried to make "depot_idx" as arrays but in vain ?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```depot_idx``` is a list.  so ```data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0]``` is clearly not valid.

Comment: `depot_idx` is a list, you can't use it as index in another list. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you for your reactivity, in fact I want to add time window constraints for each vehicle starting/ending nodes (which are called here 'depot'). The only problem I think is concerning indexes and lists.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a list item by giving another list (`depot_idx` is a list):

```
depot_idx = data['depot'] = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For accessing items in a list you need to use integers or slices that are representing the indexes you want to access.
In your case you need to pass an integer because your trying to access then the first element of the item (index 0):

```
data['time_windows'][YOUR_INTEGER][0]
```

Comment: Thank you UPetit for your response. In fact I want to add time window constraints for each vehicle starting/ending nodes (which are called here 'depot'). The only problem I think is concerning indexes and lists.
What you mean by [Your_integer], because here my integers are starting points("Data['depot']")

Comment: `data['time_windows']` is a list so the only way to access one item here is to provide an index (integer) of the item you want to access (from 0 to `len(data['time_windows'])-1`). You can't put an array, it has to be an index (or slice).
Could you please help me better understand what does `data['depot'] = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]` mean?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of  `data['depot'] = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]` is defining the nodes of departure, I am trying to solve a CVRPTW proble (Capacity Vehicle routing problem with time windows) . So, first, I needed to define 2 matrixes (Distance and time). So using  `data['depot'] = [ 0, 0, 0, 0]` , I defined my departures as nodes [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ] and respectively I defined the end nodes as `data['ends'] = [ 5, 5, 5, 5]` that's the only aim of them. Concerning the values we can put whatever we want and that's exactly the goal of the code. 
Thank you a lot Upetit.

Comment: Given we have 4 vehicules, each vehicule will start from 0 and end in 5. That's why I putted 4 integers in the list (4 vehicules --> 4 values)

Answer (score 0):

```py
depot_idx = data['depot']
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
        data['time_windows'][depot_idx][0],
        data['time_windows'][depot_idx][1])
```

1. Here, `depot_idx` is a list.
2. You mismatch index and node index

so this should work:

```py
depot_idx = data['depot']
for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
    start_index = routing.Start(vehicle_id) # solver index space
    start_node = depot_idx[vehicle_id] # your index space or
    # start_node = manager.IndexToNode(start_index)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(start_index).SetRange(
        data['time_windows'][start_node][0],
        data['time_windows'][start_node][1])
```

side note: Here you have `manager.IndexToNode(start_index) == start_node` BUT the opposite is undefined aka you can't use `manager.NodeToIndex(start_node)` since the result is ambiguous (i.e. not a single integer) actually the result should be `[routing.Start(v) for v in range(data['num_vehicles'])]` but since API should return an integer NodeToIndex() is **undefined** for start/end nodes...

Comment: Thank A lot @Mizux for your help, you saved my life. Btw I was waiting for you to show up, I've already saw your contributions about CVRPTW. all is working, but I have a concern : 

The error is : 
File "C:\Users\h.lakhdar\Desktop\CVRP_TW_V05 13.05.2022 (brouillon _ Version améliorée) spyder V2.py", line 223, in main time_dimension.CumulVar (start_node).SetRange (time_window [0] ,
File"C:\Users\h.lakhdar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\sitepackages\ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 2390,in SetRange
    return _pywrapcp.IntExpr_SetRange(self, l, u)

Exception: CP Solver fail`

Comment: In fact, I figured out the error, it was concerning slack time. it's you again on Github haha!

Comment: Can I share with you the whole code ? @Mizux